# Is there any way to improve this SARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I am using the SARIMA model to forecast timeseries using 98 days of train data and 4 days test data. There is seasonality and non-stationarity in my data. As shown in the ACF and PACF plots attached. Using the SARIMA model, generated a model with the summary attached. I have tried chnaging different parameters in the SARIMA model to see if I can get a better fit but all of them worsen the fit. The current model does not do a reasonable prediction for the test data and I would appreciate any thoughts in this regard.

[ACF and PACF plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfyt4.png)
[SARIMA model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxj4t.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using fable::ARIMA to make an autamted search of best model fit (either by AIC or BIC)

IAF your model still outputs no reasonable forecast I would really recommend migrating your analysis to structural time series models.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried grid search but the models don't improve that much. Could you please explain a little more about the structural time series models? or a good reference that I can look it up there?